# C#-Event when any textfield gains focus (also in other programms)?

Tags: c#, events

I'm currently thinking about programming an on screen extension to the physical keyboard in C#. I would like the programm to pop on top whenever a textfield is focused. Is there something like a global event for noticing that the user focused a 'typable' field? Google couldn't help.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Windows UI Automation API might give you what you need. You can google this and play with different events like OnFocusChangedHandler and then query the element properties to check if it's a textbox.